# How to print two input file ranges only if they overlap

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning python (2.7) and try to print the two file ranges ony if they overlap.

Say in file input1.txt, I have-

```
p1234: 4-5, 7-12, 15-19
p5678: 7-59, 78-345
p4356: 3-4, 6-10
```

And in file input2.txt-

```
p1234: 1-3, 6-13, 16-20, 22-25
p4356: 9-10
```

From this two input fies, I want to retain only those ranges that overlap with each other for each id (leftmost column in each file) in both input files and discard other ranges.

That is, the two output files will be as follows:

output1.txt-

```
p1234: 7-12, 15-19
p4356: 6-10
```

output2.txt-

```
p1234: 6-13, 16-20
p4356: 9-10
```

I learn that to print only the ranges those overlap, I could use:

```
x = range(1,10)
y = range(8,20)

intersection = [i for i in x if i in y]


try:
    print x
    print y
except NameError:
    print intersection
```

and this gives:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

I could get the ranges among two from here (although the last number is overlap not shown), but I have no idea how to print only the regions that overlap from two input files after matching their ids (in the two output file formats). Please help.

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: I think you are close! How about defining a function where you input one range and a list of ranges and return True or False. You would then loop every range with the ranges from the opposite file.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comment and to further use what you have started. Consider this function as an example:

```
def intersect_or_not(range_, list_of_ranges):
    for range2_ in list_of_ranges:
        intersections = [i for i in range_ if i in range2_]
        if intersections:
            return True # return also breaks (if one range intersected you have a match!)
    return False

x = range(1,10)
y = [range(8,20),range(9,20)]
   
print(intersect_or_not(x,y))
#True
```

I think you know what to do! :)

## Update:

Ok this got a bit overcomplicated but I'll post it anyway.
Assuming you read in the files to tuples (startpos, endpos) you could find the values like this:

```
def intersect_or_not(range_, list_of_ranges):
    for range2_ in list_of_ranges:
        intersections = [i for i in range_ if i in range2_]
        if intersections:
            return True
    return False
        

list1 = [(4,5), (7,12), (15,19)]
list2 = [(1,3), (6,13), (16,20), (22,25)]

#output 1
[i for i in list1 if intersect_or_not(range(*i),[range(*ii) for ii in list2])]
# [(7, 12), (15, 19)]

#output 2
[i for i in list2 if intersect_or_not(range(*i),[range(*ii) for ii in list1])]
# [(6, 13), (16, 20)]
```

Comment: You can maybe also play around with the np.where() and the pd.dataframe.merge() functions to achieve a more vectorized solution

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for poitning this out @2Obe. I'm 100% sure this can be optimized.

Comment: thanks for your reply sir,  could you kindly explain how can I match my two input and after matching their ids, print only the regions those are overlapped. Its way beyond my python .. Thanks

Comment: @Bob no problem. I updated the answer. I must say that this is far from optimal but this should definitely push you in the right direction. Your question was originally very broad including many steps. #1 read files to appropiate format, #2 function of some sort to return matches (and possibly already writing to new file)